# Writing a mini-language with haskell, trouble with "while" statements and blocks { }

Tags: haskell, mini-language

EDIT: problem partially solved, skip to the bottom for update.

I'm writing a small language using haskell, and I've made a lot of progress, but I am having trouble implementing statements that use blocks, like "{ ... }".  I've implemented support for If statements like so in my parser file:

```
stmt = skip +++ ifstmt +++ assignment +++ whilestmt

ifstmt = symbol "if" >>
         parens expr >>= \c ->
         stmt >>= \t ->
         symbol "else" >>
         stmt >>= \e ->
         return $ If c t e

whilestmt = symbol "while" >>
            parens expr >>= \c ->
        symbol "\n" >>
        symbol "{" >>
        stmt >>= \t ->
        symbol "}" >>
        return $ While c t

expr = composite +++ atomic
```

And in the Syntax file:

```
class PP a where 
  pp :: Int -> a -> String

instance PP Stmt where
  pp ind (If c t e) = indent ind ++ 
                      "if (" ++ show c ++ ") \n" ++ 
                      pp (ind + 2) t ++
                      indent ind ++ "else\n" ++
                      pp (ind + 2) e
  pp ind (While c t) = indent ind ++
                   "while (" ++ show c ++") \n" ++
                   "{" ++ pp (ind + 2) t ++ "}" ++
                   indent ind
```

Something is wrong with the while statement, and I don't understand what. The logic seems correct, but when I run the code I get the following error:

```
EDIT: Fixed the first problem based on the first reply, now it is not recognizing my while statment which I assume comes from this:
exec :: Env -> Stmt -> Env
exec env (If c t e) = 
    exec env ( if eval env c == BoolLit True then t else e )
exec env (While c t) =
    exec env ( if eval env c == BoolLit True then t )
```

The file being read from looks like this:

```
x = 1; c = 0;
if (x < 2) c = c + 1; else ;
-- SEPARATE FILES FOR EACH
x = 1; c = 1;
while (x < 10)
{
  c = c * x;
  x = x + 1;
}
c
```

I've tried to understand the error report but nothing I've tried solves the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`>>` and `>>=` bind tighter than `$`. Try using

```
return (While c t)
```

instead of

```
return $ While c t
```

And also, put parenthesis around the lambda expression on the right hand side of `>>=`.

Or just use do-notation:

```
whilestmt = do
    symbol "while"
    c <- parens expr
    symbol "\n"
    symbol "{"
    t <- stmt
    symbol "}"
    return $ While c t
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in Haskell, an `if` statement always has to have an `else` in addition to a `then`.  Your implementation of `exec` for `While` specifies what to do when the condition is `True`, but says nothing about the behavior when the condition is `False`.  In fact, your code only executes the body of the while loop once when the condition is `True`, but it should keep executing it (and threading the updates to the environment) until the condition becomes `False`.  So, something like this:

```
exec env (While c t) = execWhile env c t

execWhile env c t | eval env c == BoolLit True = let env' = exec t in execWhile env' c t
                  | otherwise = env
```

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that you duplicated the question, and already got an answer...